# Installed node 9.0 but not npm

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, npm

I want to install node and npm in Ubutun 16.04. I have followed the installation guide from node team with these commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

and I have problems with npm installation. If I run `node -v` I can see

```
v9.2.0
```

But if I run `npm -v` I see

```
/usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

why is not installed npm? any clue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the package `npm`.

```
sudo apt-get install -y npm
```